# if (model.Building.Address == null) not working, doesn't compile - why?

Tags: c#

I got a line of code that wouldn't compile, red curly underline:

[image]

However, if I use model.Building.Address.Equals(null), no issues:

[image]

The actual error message is:

[image]

And Address is a regular property defined like this:

[image]

[image]

**Question: why check for (model.Building.Address == null) doesn't compile ???**

Comment: What is the `Address` type here? Is it a `struct`?

Comment: Added more info, please reload

Comment: Firstly, please post code as code, not screenshots. Secondly, you still didn't say what `Address` is.

Comment: No more screenshots!!!!!!!

Comment: DavidG, why, what's the problem?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: understand, however it is not possible to add some drawings to code text, like the red frames with comments above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `model.Building.Address == null` doesn't compile then for sure that's a structure (I mean `Address` is non-nullable type and it's a `struct` actually)

Answer (score 8):

The reason the comparison to `null` may not work is that `model.Building.Address` is a non-nullable value type, i.e. a `struct`. Such value types cannot be `null`, so the compiler issues an error.

The comparison `model.Building.Address.Equals(null)` will compile, but it is as good as having no comparison at all, because it always returns `false`.

Two ways to make it work are changing the type used for `Address` from `struct` to `class`, or making `Address` nullable by appending a question mark `?` after the name of its type.

Comment: Exactly the case, it was a struct. Changed to Class.